# Can't calculate $I=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{\cos x}{x^2+1} \, dx$ using residues

Tags: improper-integrals, residue-calculus

I tried to calculate the integral
$$I=\int_{-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{\cos x}{x^2+1} \, dx$$
using residues and got
$$I=2\pi i \text{ Res}\left(\frac{\cos x}{x^2+1},(x,i)\right)=\pi  \cosh 1\approx 4.8$$
which is nonsense because the graph of $y=\frac{\cos x}{x^2+1}$ is between $-\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ and $\frac{1}{x^2+1}$, the area between these two curves is $2\pi$ and $I\approx 4.8$ is too much.

*Mathematica* gives $I=\frac{\pi}{e}\approx 1.15573$ which makes much more sense.

> My questions are.
>
> - Given that my use of residue is wrong, what does $\pi  \cosh 1$    represent?
> - Why residue is wrong in this example?

Comment: What contour did you pick?

Comment: I think is better to use the function $f(z)=\frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}$, since for $x\in\Bbb R$,  $\Re(f(x))=\frac{\cos x}{x^2+1}$. [Here](https://personal.us.es/bassas/doc/pdf/mmi/temas/Tema06.pdf) you have exactly the same integral calculated. (PAge 9, In Spanish).

Comment: @AryamanMaithani This one https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/9/93/ContourDiagram.png/375px-ContourDiagram.png

Comment: @Raffaele: That is what I suspected. It is better to use Tito Eliatron's function in that case. The integral (over the semi-circular arc) of the function you chose does not vanish in the limit. (In fact, using the correct function, you can actually calculate what it is, in the limit!)

Comment: @TitoEliatron Thank you so much! Could not ask more. Amusing that the integral in Spanish is female. In Italian is male :)

Comment: @AryamanMaithani Thank you! Still digesting complex analysis after 40 years :/

Comment: @AryamanMaithani ...and $\pi\cosh 1$? What does it represent?

Comment: @Raffaele: I'm not sure what it "represents" but it equals the sum of your desired integral $I$ along with the integral over the semi-circular contour, in the limit as $R \to \infty$. In other words, once you actually calculate the integral to be $\pi/e$, you've shown that the integral over the semi-circle (in the limit) is $\pi(\cosh 1 - 1/e)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need to do is to calculate the residue of $\dfrac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}$
then get the real part of it, since $\cos(z)$ is not a bounded function on the upper complex plane but $e^{iz}$ is.